# What happens if I go past Phase 10 in Phase 10 Twist?

Tags: phase-10

In the Phase 10 Twist rules, they say the winner is whoever gets past phase 10. Say I'm on Phase 9, and I go out, dropping all my cards. I'm supposed to go 3 spaces forward, but can't because Phase 10 is the only spot left. Do I win automatically or do I sit on Phase 10 spot and play that spot to win?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The rules](http://www.boardgamecapital.com/game_rules/phase-10-twist.pdf) cover this, under the "If you land on the PHASE 10 Space..." section:

> You may skip over the 10th Phase space by earning a 2 or 3-space move from one of the two preceding spaces.

So you indeed win if you go out while on Phase 9.